# How to get all the URLTemplate of method names from the WCF Rest service in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, wcf

I have a rest service URL as below
http://XXXXXXXX/RestServices/Project.svc

This SVC has two methods,

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "UserLogin")]
    ResultInfo Login(Login objLogin);

[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "SaveUser")]
    ResultInfo User(User objUser);
```

The Method Name are Login and User, but the UriTemplate Names are UserLogin and SaveUser accordingly.

I want to get the Output in C# list as below

```
UserLogin
SaveUser
```

Need your help on this.

Comment: Please try to provide more details like what you want and how you are populating your list?

Comment: List<String> str = new List<string>(); in this list of string, i need the URLTemplate names by consuming this WCF service URL

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Method names by using the following method

In ASPX Page:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstMethodName" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true"
        Style="height: 150px; width:300px; overflow: auto;"></asp:ListBox>
```

In Code Behind:

```
string wsdlUrl = "http://XXXXXXXX/RestServices/Project.svc?wsdl"; // WCF wsdl address
                XmlTextReader myReader = new XmlTextReader(wsdlUrl);
                if (ServiceDescription.CanRead(myReader))
                {
                    ServiceDescription myDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(myReader);

                    foreach (PortType pt in myDescription.PortTypes)
                    {
                        foreach (Operation op in pt.Operations)
                        {
                            lstMethodName.Items.Add(op.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Add the Namespace :

```
 using System.Web.Services.Description;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
```